# iPhone - NSMutableArray inside a Custom Object. When to release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, memory-management, nsmutablearray

When should I be releasing `[self.activeLocations]`, which is an `NSMutableArray` inside my custom object? I am also getting memory leaks in `initWithValue`.

Also the `Location` object below. Am I calling this and releasing this properly?

Method in Custom Object.m:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.couponId = [value valueForKey:@"couponId"];
        self.couponName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"couponName"];
        self.qrCode = [value valueForKeyPath:@"description"];
        self.companyName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"companyName"];
        self.categoryName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"categoryName"];
        self.distance = [value valueForKeyPath:@"distance"];

        NSDictionary *activeLocationsDict = [value valueForKeyPath:@"activeLocations"];
        //self.activeLocations = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.activeLocations = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (id val in activeLocationsDict) {
            // Add JSON objects to array.
            Location *l = [[Location alloc] initWithValue:val];
            [self.activeLocations addObject:l];
            [l release];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    couponId = nil;
    couponName = nil;
    qrCode = nil;
    companyName = nil;
    categoryName = nil;
    distance = nil;
    activeLocations = nil;
}
```

My Custom Object.h

```
@interface Coupon : NSObject {
    NSNumber *couponId;
    NSString *couponName;
    NSString *qrCode;
    NSString *companyName;
    NSString *categoryName;
    NSString *distance;
    NSMutableArray *activeLocations;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *couponId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *couponName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *qrCode;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *companyName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *categoryName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *distance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *activeLocations;

- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value;
```

This is how I'm using the above `initWithValue`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createArrayOfCoupons:(NSString *)value {
    NSDictionary *responseJSON = [value JSONValue];

    // Loop through key value pairs in JSON response.
    //NSMutableArray *couponsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSMutableArray *couponsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id val in responseJSON) {
        // Add JSON objects to array.
        Coupon *c = [[Coupon alloc] initWithValue:val];
        [couponsArray addObject:c];
        [c release];
    }

    return couponsArray;
}
```

I get memory leaks on `initWithValue` in the above method as well...

[image]

`Location` Custom Object:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.locationId = [value valueForKeyPath:@"locationId"];
        self.companyName = [value valueForKeyPath:@"companyName"];
        self.street1 = [value valueForKeyPath:@"street1"];
        self.street2 = [value valueForKeyPath:@"street2"];
        self.suburb = [value valueForKeyPath:@"suburb"];
        self.state = [value valueForKeyPath:@"state"];
        self.postcode = [value valueForKeyPath:@"postcode"];
        self.phoneNo = [value valueForKeyPath:@"phoneNo"];
        self.latitude = [value valueForKeyPath:@"latitude"];
        self.longitude = [value valueForKeyPath:@"longitude"];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    locationId = nil;
    companyName = nil;
    street1 = nil;
    street2 = nil;
    suburb = nil;
    state = nil;
    postcode = nil;
    phoneNo = nil;
    latitude = nil;
    longitude = nil;
}
```

Comment: You can release it in dealloc na?

Comment: Can you show us your `-dealloc` method?

Comment: you must call [super dealloc] as the last statement in dealloc, not the first or you'll crash (since the class memory itself and thus the members it points to are invalid after [super dealloc].

Comment: Also, in dealloc since the memory is going away it is not necessary to set the members to nil.  You must *release* the members and there are two ways of doing this:  1)  You can call [member release], and 2) you can say self.member = nil.  The self. notation tells the Obj-C runtime to release any members that have properties declared with retain.  It is less common to do #2 and can sometimes have strange results.  In dealloc you should always just use the first method [member release] on all members and then call [super dealloc].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (id)init {
   ....
}
```

Get rid of this. It does nothing.

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    [super init];
```

There's a specific pattern you should use for initialization:

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSString *)value {
    if (( self = [super init] )) {
      // everything except the return
    }
    return self;
}
```

Finally, to answer your actual question, assuming you're using `retain` with your property, there's two places you'll need to release.

Here's the first:

```
self.activeLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**Why**: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` makes your code own the object by retaining it. But the property set also claims ownership by retaining it. You don't really want this `NSMutableArray` owned by the code *and* your custom object, you want it owned by your object.

My suggestion is to just use this:

```
self.activeLocations = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The second place is in your dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.activeLocations = nil;

    // ...and everything else you've set as a property using retain

    [super dealloc];
}
```

(Personally, I've gone back and forth on whether to use dot notation in dealloc rather than `[activeLocations release];`. I'm favouring setting to nil using the property now, which puts all the memory management rules in a single location.)

Apple has a great document on memory management you should read: [Memory Management Programming Guide: Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have modified my code to add in your answers. I do get memory leaks though. I have added more code to my original question above.

Comment: Aha! Yes, your dealloc is wrong. First, you need to go through the property setter to get property behavior. foo = nil only sets the ivar to nil; if you want to release it, you must use self.foo = nil. And you MUST call [super dealloc] at the END of your dealloc. You need to think that [super dealloc] invalidates the entire object, including the references to what you're trying to release.

Comment: Thanks, your above suggestions and answers work perfectly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Awesome. :) The most important thing with Cocoa memory management is to think in terms of ownership. Do you need the object? Then own it. Are you finished with it, and you own it? Let go. Once you wrap your head around how simple it really is, it's… well, really simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your overridden `-init` method is **completely unnecessary** because by default when a method is invoked, the runtime will perform an upward traversal of the inheritance hierarchy until the specified method is found, so it will find `NSObject`'s `-init` method and invoke it.

Second, you should invoke `release` on all of your owned properties (ones with `copy` or `retain`) in your overridden `-dealloc` method.

Third, in your case, when you call the property setter passing in an object that is already owned locally, you must send the object the `release` message after invoking the setter to correctly hand off ownership of the object to the receiver.

There are two ways to do this:

One way is to create an object that you own using `alloc`, `copy` or `new`, and then invoke the property setter, passing in that object, then send it the `release` message.

Another way is to pass in an autoreleased object to the property setter, which will then `retain` or `copy` its argument and thereby obtain ownership

Comment: If I release all of my owned properties which are (nonatomic, retain) in -dealloc, then I get a message sent to deallocated instance error.

Comment: If that's the case, Fulvio, you'll have to share more code. Memory management should be simple: Release every time you've staked a claim on an object. If you're experiencing a crash like this, it means you're releasing somewhere where you **don't** own the object.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *when* you should be releasing it is a question of whether or not the activeLocations array and all the elements in that array (remember each element in the array is retained by the array itself) are necessary throughout the lifetime of the Location object.

If you use the activeLocations array for some temporary purpose, for example in a method or chain of methods, then don't need it again, or you plan to refresh its members at some later time when you need it next, then it makes sense to release the array (and its elements, which is automatic) when you're done using it, in whatever function last uses the array.  You will use the convention

`self.activeLocations = nil;`

to let the runtime system release the array and set the member to nil.

If, on the other hand, the activeLocations array data is mandatory for the Locations object to function and must exist as long as the Location object exists, then you will want to release the array inside the dealloc method of the Location object, for example:

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [activeLocations release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

As it happens, you're pretty much always going to want to release member objects such as activeLocations in a dealloc method.  This ensures that when the Location object is released the members it contains are cleaned up.  Remember that Objective-C does not call methods on null pointers, so if you have previously set activeLocations to nil the call in dealloc is a safe no-op.

Given then that you'll always set things up to release in dealloc, now you really just have to ask yourself if you need a release/recreate phase somewhere in your object lifecycle (again, determined by frequency-of-use requirements).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're asking. In the initWithValue: method that you've shared, you are double-retaining the array. It should be released or autoreleased once within initWithValue:.

The array should be released a second time in the custom object's dealloc method.